# How to display image in diamond shape in android?

Tags: android, xml, view

How to display image in diamond shape in android with some rounded in sides?

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: try with this previous answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429103/3614180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the below library

https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView

There is available more than 15 shape.

Like: Circle View, RoundRect View, CutCorner View, Arc View, Diagonal View, Triangle View, Star View, polygon view, DottedEdgesCutCorner View, etc.

Also, you can add your own shape by using ShapeOfView library.

Using this library, you can make a different type of shapes images.

Comment: @D prince but in this library we can't play with diamond view.

Comment: okay for this, i am created my own diamond view and set through this library. thank you.